# Drupal 6: extracting input field of a search form out of div

Tags: search, drupal-6

The Drupal documentation about theming search forms says:
* $search['search_theme_form']: Text input area wrapped in a div.

My html page which i want to make a drupal theme uses a special search form so i don't want the form's elements to be wrapped into a div. How can i get the clean search form elements not wrapped into div?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the Drupal documentation pretty much says it all: http://drupal.org/node/45295

If you just want to remove the `div` container overwrite the template `search-theme-form.tpl.php` or whatever template is responsible for the input search field. You have the instruction on how to overwrite in the link above.

If you want more customization than you'll have to do step #2 from the Drupal tutorial.

So from this:

```
// @file /modules/search/search-theme-form.tpl.php
<div id="search" class="container-inline">
  <?php print $search_form; ?>
</div>
```

To this:

```
// @file /sites/all/themes/your-active-theme/search-theme-form.tpl.php
<?php print $search_form; ?>
```

Don't forget to clear the Drupal's site cache.